# Meteor: Sending file through HTTP library to Echonest for analysis

Tags: javascript, json, http, meteor, echonest

I am using Meteor for a web application project and am trying to send a file using the HTTP library and get back a JSON object using a get request. I need to send a POST request to the echonest server where the file is sent as a binary data object. From there, I need to make two GET requests: one to get the url and one to get the data at that url. The last two steps are not a problem, but I'm finding it very difficult to send the raw binary data. Here's what I've found so far:

The Meteor HTTP library cannot send binary data in a POST request because it calls JSON.stringify on the data being sent.
An XHR cannot be used to send the data from the client because the server I am trying to communicate with blocks client-side connections to their service.

So what I want to know is if there is another library/package that can be used with Meteor to send the binary data?
Alternatively, is there a way to get an XHR request to work on Meteor server-side?